# Details in Proving Kruskal's Theorem (The finite trees are well-quasi-ordered by the topological minor relation.)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In Diestel's Graph Theory book he gives a proof of Kruskal's Theorem. I am trying to go through the details to make sure I fully understand.

**Kruskal's Theorem** The finite trees are well-quasi-ordered by the topological minor relation.

Before the proof even begins, we define a new relation, (instead of using the topological minor relation). I've copied the paragraph below which comes before the proof starts.

*"We shall base the proof ... on the following notion of an embedding between rooted trees, which strengthens the usual embedding as a topological minor. Consider two trees $T$ and $T'$, with roots $r$ and $r'$ say. Let us write $T \leq T'$ if there exists an isomorphism $\varphi$, from some subdivision of $T$ to a subtree $T''$ of $T'$, that preserves the tree-order on $V(T)$ associated with $T$ and $r$. (Thus is $x < y$ in $T$ then $\varphi(x) < \varphi(y)$ in $T'$) As one easily checks, this is a quasi-ordering on the class of all rooted trees."*

The topological minor relation says that $T \leq T'$ if a graph isomorphic to $T$ is a topological minor of $T'$, i.e. $T'$ contains a subdivision of a graph isomorphic to $T$.

**Question 1.** How is this "new" relation (described in quotations) stronger? When I read it, it sounds like a different way to describe the topological minor relation. Is it because of the preservation of the tree-order? Or because we are restricting it to only rooted trees?

**Question 2.** Diestel states that you can easily check this is a quasi-ordering on the rooted trees. I want to make sure I understand this as well. A quasi-ordering must be reflexive and transitive, (not necessarily antisymmetric).

For reflexive, can we let $\varphi$ be the identity? This is an isomorphism from $T$ to itself. Clearly this preserves tree-order and we will get $T \leq T$, for any $T$ in the class of rooted trees.

For transitive, we know $\exists \varphi_1$ an isomorphism from a subdivision of $T_1$ to a subtree $T_2'$ of $T_2$, and $\varphi_2$ an isomorphism from a subdivision of $T_2$ to a subtree $T_3'$ of $T_3$, (tree-order preserving). So that $T_1 \leq T_2$ and $T_2 \leq T_3$. Now, we need to find a $\varphi$ satisfying the conditions so that $T_1 \leq T_3$. Can we let $\varphi = \varphi_2 \circ \varphi_1$? Then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism from the same subdivision of $T_1$ to the same subtree $T_3'$ of $T_3$.

My "question" is if my thinking is correct.

I would greatly appreciate any help/explanation/comments!

Comment: The only strengthening happening here is that it's respecting the orientation on the tree; for example, if your tree was just a path with some vertices, then "reflecting it" by swapping the end points doesn't preserve the order structure induced from the root - but is a graph isomorphism.  For the second part, you need to pull back the second subdivision all the way back to $T_1$; simply composing them doesn't quite make sense, because the image of $T_1$ might receive further subdivision in $T_2$ before mapping into $T_3$.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I see the issues that my composition of functions would have. I’ve only seen pullbacks in my little experience with manifolds, where if we have $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$, the pullback is $f^*g: X \rightarrow Z$, where $f^*g$ is just $g \circ f$. Which is why that was my first instinct. I realize that the issue is that we’re not just going from one tree to the next ($T_1 \rightarrow T_2 \rightarrow T_3$), because we take a subdivision of the tree first. So how could we write $\varphi$ in this situation?

Comment: If $R_1$ is the subdivision of $T_1$ for $\phi_1$ then $R_1$ is isomorphic with $T_2'$.  So if you add a vertex between two vertices $v_1, v_2 \in V(T_2')$ then just add a vertex between the vertices $\phi_1^{-1}(v_1)$ and $\phi_1^{-1}(v_2)$.  This will give you a further subdivision of $R_1$ and thus of $T_1$ which will be the one you need.